# Valor máximo por categoria

Tags: sql, select

Eu estou fazendo um trabalho no qual eu gostaria de mostrar o saldo máximo de cada tipo de conta com `subselect` dentro do `SELECT`.

**Algo mais ou menos assim:**

```
CodConta ---------------------tipo ------------------ saldo maximo
2568468                      Salario                  6200
7895465                      Corrente                 9000
2315467                      Poupança                 32000
```

**A tabela se chama "conta" e possui os dados:**

- codconta
- tipo
- saldo
- Data_abertura
- Agencia

**Eu consegui algo parecido, porém mostra apenas os valores e um para cada coluna:**

```
SELECT
  MAX((SELECT saldo FROM conta WHERE tipo = 'Salario' AND codconta = s1.codconta)) "Conta salario",
  MAX((SELECT saldo FROM conta WHERE tipo = 'Corrente' AND codconta = s1.codconta)) "Conta corrente",
  MAX((SELECT saldo FROM conta WHERE tipo = 'Poupança' AND codconta = s1.codconta)) "Conta Poupança"
FROM(
  SELECT
    *
  FROM conta
)s1
```

**Estrutura da tabela:**

```
CREATE TABLE Conta (
      CodConta NUMBER(6) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      Tipo VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
      Saldo DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL,
      Data_Abertura DATE,
      Agencia NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
      FOREIGN KEY(Agencia) REFERENCES Agencia(NumAgencia)
   )
```

Comment: precisa ser por sub-query mesmo? pq isso é facil e bem mais simples usando `group by`

Comment: Select tipo,max(saldo) as saldomax from tabela group by tipo vide https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: Terei que pensar em uma outra situação que me obrigue a utilizar uma subquery no select, pois é um exercício de um trabalho pede isso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, utilizando GROUP BY deve resolver, ex:

```
SELECT tipo, MAX(saldo) AS 'saldo' FROM conta GROUP BY TIPO;
```

Depois avisa se deu certo.
Valeu!

Comment: Este código funcionou, muito obrigado, o problema é que eu precisava elaborar uma situação na qual seja necessário utilizar um Subselect dentro do select e minha dificuldade é elaborá-la. Enunciados do tipo: "Apresentar o saldo maximo para cada tipo de conta" e depois montar um SQL